# WMI Access Denied on Win10Pro with local acc

Tags: windows-10, wmi, workgroup

I have two Win10 Pro machines in the workgroup.

A while ago I was able to connect from one to other through WMI with local account with admins rights. I use wbemtest to test the connection.

But now I have **Windows 10 Pro 1803** on both and can't connect. Get Access Denied error.

I added key "*AllowAnonymousCallback*", checked firewall exception for WMI, WMI security rights for root and cimv2. WMI, DCOM and RPC services are running.

Checked *Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts to Classic - local users authenticate as themselfes* and  *Network security LAN Manager authentication level to Send LM & NTLM responses, use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated*.

Also I added hosts to winrm.

I can connect to Windows 7 machine with local admin account, without any problems bu not to Win10.

I can open network shares on Win10 with local admin credentials.

Did MS change something for local admins?

Comment: I think you should ask this on [Super User](https://www.superuser.com). This site is for programming questions, not software issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this for programming, wbemtest just for test.